# Java String::replaceAll only replaces first occurrence (probably incorrect regex)

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to retrieve some page from confluence and render it inside my own application. I'm using regex to replace confluence image urls with my endpoints that provides authenticated proxy between confluence and my app's user.

regex is:

`(src|href)="\/download\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)`

and whole replacement line is:

`html = html.replaceAll("(src|href)=\"\\/download\\/(.*)\\/(.*)\\/(.*)", "$1=\"" + baseUrl + "/rest/myapp/documents/"+instance+"/$2/$3/$4");`

I'm trying to replace

`src="/download/attachments/65591/` with `src="https://myapp/rest/myapp/documents/{instance}/thumbnails/65591/`

I tested this regex using different tools, including https://regex101.com/r/8r77OF/4 but while my test results are positive, my application only replaces the first occurrence.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `.*` is greedy and matches the rest of your string, so you only have one match.Maybe you can make a test case with a string that has two instances. Maybe you should include the closing " mark, or for the last clause us [^"]* so that it will match everything that isn't a quote.

Comment: You are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2067492/matt) suggested, `.*` is greedy so replacing my regex with

```
"(src|href)=\"\\/download\\/(.*?)\\/(.*?)\\/(.*?)\\/"
```

solved the problem. Thanks!